# PayPal Authorization-Code Rest API failedBecause=risk_decline

Tags: paypal, authorization, paypal-sandbox

Im trying to recieve a Authorization-Code like described here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/#obtain-users-consent
see "Request URL sample: grant consent"

```html
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize
  ?client_id=Client-Id
  &response_type=code
  &scope=profile+email+address+phone
    +https%3A%2F%2Furi.paypal.com%2Fservices%2Fpaypalattributes
  &redirect_uri=http://example.com/myapp/return.php
```

My Problem is that, I can't login. Im getting the hint "we can't log you in" and in the redirect uri I see "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin?resType=code&failedBecause=risk_decline". Im using the same Sandbox User when testing to obtain the Code with the new iOS SDK without a problem, so it can't be a user problem. Im really stucked at this point because I have no 
idea why this is not working also there are no error codes at all and so I can't debug.